# Is Homeo(M) locally path-connected for a general topological manifold?

Tags: manifolds, topological-groups, geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

I am wondering if there exists a closed topological manifold for which Homeo$(M)$ is not locally path-connected. If $M$ admits a smooth structure, then one can prove that Homeo$(M)$ is in fact locally path-connected, but what about non-smooth topological manifolds. For instance, is the homeomorphism group of $E_8$ locally path-connected?

Comment: I'd suggest posting this question to MathOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have found the answer. There is this paper by Kirby in which he proves homeomorphism group of every topological manifold is locally contractible.

Comment: then would you post this as an answer (including the reference to Kirby's paper) and accept your own answer? this would be helpful to users.